# Angular try to get specific value doesnt work

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to get data from my Firestore Collection. This works if I print my JSON. If I want now to show one value it doesn't work. To get my data I created the following:

```
    interface Note{
      imageUrl: string;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      this.notesCollection = this.afs.collection('PromotedBlogs')
      this.notes = this.notesCollection.valueChanges()
    }
```

and I want to show the imageUrl in a img. To do so I tried the following, but it doesn't work, it just shows the grey background:

```
<div class="blogrow">
    <div class="blogcolumn" style="background-color:#aaa;" *ngFor="let note of notes | async"  >
        <img src="{{ (note | async).imageUrl}}" width="100%" height="300px">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you really need the second async pipe on note within the ngFor? Because you already have an async pipe on notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of issues here. It is difficult to say with the limited code you've provided.

I'm working on the assumption that if you did something `<div> {{notes | json}} </div>` in your template it would successfully display your JSON. This assumption is based off of your comment:

> "This works if I print my JSON"

A potential issue that sticks out is your duplicate use of the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) and your use of brackets in the `src` attribute of the image tag.

Since you unwrap the Observable in your looping logic (`*ngFor="let note of notes | async"`) you don't need to then try to unwrap it again when accessing the individual properties of the `note` objects. Additionally in Angular you do not need to use the "squiggly bracket notation for the `src` attribute of an image tag.

You can try to update your image tag to `<img [src]="note.imageUrl" width="100%" height="300px">` and see if that fixes your issue.

If not you may try to hardcode the path to verify your path is actually correct to begin with, something like: `<img src="path/to/image.png" width="100%" height="300px">`

Comment: yes you were right, i only had to delete the 'async' part in my img